# Child inside Relative Layout onclicklistener and onclick not working

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, android-relativelayout

I'm getting confused with this. I have a RelativeLayout with 2 child, LinearLayout and ImageView.

in this case, the ImageView would be in front of the LinearLayout. Then the imageview is added with onclicklistener.

Problem is that OnClickListener become not functioning. doesn't detect any clicking event at all.

Then tried to change from OnClickListener to clickable:true and onClick:method. Clicking event is detected but is unable to find Specified method.

Anyone had any idea?

Comment: Could you please post your code and layout files? And why don't you use only the ImageView? Do you want to add more child views? If not the relative and linear layout is useless.

Comment: share some code! Your layout and activtiy onCreate method should do it

Answer (score 3):

imageview.bringToFront() Try This

Answer (score 1):

Try **imageview.bringToFront()** in class file.